# How to wrap a collection in a single parent tag

Tags: java, xml, collections, jaxb

I have a class called XmlSource which contains a collection of objects of type XmlSourceAudioLang, and the XmlSourceAudioLang class has a field called language which I need to marshal to XML, i.e. :

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class XmlSource {

  @XmlElement(name="original_audio_language", nillable=true) 
  protected Set<XmlSourceAudioLang> originalAudio;

}
```

and

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class XmlSourceAudioLang {

  @XmlElement(nillable = true)
  private String language;

}
```

With this setup, JAXB generates a original_audio_language tag for each object in the collection:

```
<original_audio_language>
  <language>Ukrainian</language>
</original_audio_language>
<original_audio_language>
  <language>Russian</language>
</original_audio_language>
```

Is there a way to configure the binding so that there is only one parent original_audio_language tag ?

Answer (score 9):

Assuming that you mean that you want this:

```
<original_audio_language>
  <language>Ukrainian</language>
  <language>Russian</language>
</original_audio_language>
```

Then try this:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class XmlSource {
  @XmlElementWrapper(name="original_audio_language") 
  @XmlElement(name="language")
  protected Set<XmlSourceAudioLang> originalAudio;
}
```

---

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class XmlSourceAudioLang {  
  @XmlValue
  private String language;    
}
```